# How to do password synchronization between openIDM and openDJ

Tags: java, federated-identity, opendj, openidm

I want to do synchronization between openIDM and openDJ. The synchronization works for all the fields except the password field. I want the password to be stored in openDJ when a user is created in openIDM. What are the steps required to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use such a configuration in openidm/conf/sync.json:

```
{
    "source" : "password",
    "condition" : {
        "type" : "text/javascript",
        "source" : "object.password != null"
    },
    "transform" : {
        "type" : "text/javascript",
        "source" : "openidm.decrypt(source);"
    },
    "target" : "userPassword"
}
```

You can check out [sample2b documentation](http://openidm.forgerock.org/doc/install-guide/index.html#more-sample2b) that describes a 2-ways sync between OpenDJ and OpenIDM repo. But note that this sample does password sync only on [OpenIDM Trunk (3.0)](http://download.forgerock.org/downloads/openidm/snapshot/openidm-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip)

Comment: I am using openIDM(2.1.0) version. Will the same configuration work on it?